# Change regression line to straight shape

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm literally building my first ever linear regression in R. And I stumbled on the very last step: could you advise how to change my stepped linear regression into straight line? Is there simple visualisation command I can add? The code I wrote is:

```
MyDataSet.plot <- MyDataSet.plot + 
   geom_line(data=plotting.data2, 
             aes(x=MyXvariable, y=predicted.y, color=MyOtherIndependentVariable), 
             size=1.25) 
MyDataSet.plot
```

Please speak very elementary R to me :) Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `geom_smooth()`. You can get help pages by typing the following at the prompt in the console: `?geom_smooth()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this minimal example what you'd like to achieve?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- tribble(~x, ~y, ~col,
        1, 3, "a",
        2, 5, "a",
        3, 4, "a",
        4, 5, "a",
        1, 6, "b",
        2, 7, "b",
        3, 7, "b",
        4, 9, "b"
        )

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = col)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype = "dashed")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>